# Version intolerant serialization?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serialization

What is the current best practice to serialize objects in C# in a **version-intolerant** way?

The console application I am currently working on is taking several minutes to build an object-cache after startup that it does then use for its actual tasks. At the end of the execution, I would like to persist the cache's content to disk and reload it the next time during startup.

But the reload should fail as soon as any of the cached object's structure changes. The application should then start with an empty cache and rebuild it on the fly.

In Java, deserialization would just fail due to a modified serialVersionUID. What is the easiest way to achieve the same in C#?

I do not care about the format of the stored data. I am just looking to the easiest way to dump a bunch of objects (e.g. a Dictionary) into a file and have the reload fail as soon as the structure of an object contained in the data changes.

Comment: You can serialize objects into many formats (XML, JSON, YAML, BSON, any number of binary formats, etc.) and using many libraries (e.g. using XmlSerializer, JSON.NET, System.Text.Json, MessagePack, etc.). As we are not psychic, please can you provide more information.

Comment: I clarified the question a bit: I am looking for the easiest way to dump a bunch of objects into a file and have the reload fail as soon as one of the object's structure changes.

Comment: Is it good enough if the deserialization throws an exception to indicate incompatibility?

Comment: Yes, an exception is totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Many serialization libraries support some type of `IsRequired`-attribute for properties. This would cause deserialization to fail anytime you add a property, but not necessarily when you remove when.

You could use the assembly version to check if the data structure is identical. Assuming you have some build system that ensure that version numbers are unique. This would not care if the actual data structure had changed, only if the build is new. But it might work well enough if releases are infrequent.

Some serialization libraries can generate a *schema* for your types. You could then serialize this schema, or a hash of it, and check if this is the same when loading. There are also third party schema generators if your serialization library does not have this function.

Without more details about the actual serialization library you are planning to use it is difficult to provide any concrete recommendations.

Comment: Thank you. My question is more about finding the library than about the actual usage.
It just keeps bothering me that .NET does not seem to have a quick and easy solution for "version-intolerant serialization", something that e.g. Java offers out of the box.

Comment: @Andreas, well, there is BinaryFormatter, but it is really not something I would recommend using. But to be fair, being "version-intolerant" is one thing it does do quite well.

Comment: Yes, BinaryFormatter seems to be perfect but has been deprecated since forever unfortunately.